# facebook key hash, android keystore confusion

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, certificate, keystore

`keytool -exportcert -alias mykeystore -keystore mykeystore| openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

hello, I am using the above command to generate my facebook key hash. It asks for my password and gives me a key hash. I put this key hash in the facebook app settings, yet it does not work for my signed android app.

When I was debugging the android app, I saw the console message saying it didn't recognize "android key hash blahblahblah" so I copied "blahblahblah" into the facebook app, and that worked - my android app was able to use the facebook stuff while in debug mode. But clearly that was only for the debug keystore. Now for the real keystore the one it generates is still wrong, so a production version of my app will not be able to use facebook api.

One thing about my keystore is that it was made in eclipse. It is one keystore with two keys in it. I have noticed that eclipse keystore acts different than command line keystore things, and that they are incompatible for signing things. Yet I have already released a version of my app so I need to make due with the keys I am already using.

Insight appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `keytool -list` to list the aliases you have. If you are not sure which one you used to sign the APK you released, try both. One should work.

Comment: can you give me the full command? I did `keytool -list -keystore mykeystore` , it asked for my password and then displayed the certificate fingerprint, which is in the format `Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 2B:43:D7:57:.........` which is not the has format facebook wants. how do I list the aliases or whatever, not sure how to proceed

Comment: Use `keytool -list -v -keystore` to list the aliases (check the 'Alias name: ...') lines, then replace the alias in your original command with those.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem - debug hash key worked but production key did not. I ended up installing OpenSSL from a different source than I originally installed, re-created the hash key, and it fixed the problem. This is the site where I got OpenSSL that worked: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm.

Comment: Dude. You are a LIFE SAVER. Every other post was *HOW* to sign. I already did that so I was getting a little desperate as I had already deployed to GooglePlay and some of my beta testers were getting nasty. When I saw your comment I instantly followed your link, and used that version of OPENSSL.

Answer (score 0):

If running Cygwin on Windows, use cygpath to find the keystore:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore $(cygpath -aw ~/.android/debug.keystore) | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64    Keystore-Kennwort eingeben:  android
```

If using /cygpath/c/Users/name/... it will not work.